# Why are my list items displayed above their parent <div>?

Tags: html, css

This is happening in both Safari and Firefox. My navigation bar looks like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS looks like:

```
li {
  float: left
}

a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

For some reason, the list items are floating above the `<div>` they're inside (`#navBar`). I can't figure out why this seemingly simple design is causing problems.

[image: floating above]

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: please share the code...

Comment: Varun: isn't it easier to just view it on the site I linked?

Comment: it's giving me the same alignment of links, yes your links are stick at the top of the div#navbar you need to set some top: padding to align  middle of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: block` to `#navBar a`.

[image: Example]

Comment: @TomMarthenal - Mark the answer as completed. Since its solved

Comment: Varun: Done now, I was having to wait a few minutes until I could accept an answer.